# Converter "2012-01-01" em "2012-Jan-01" no R

Tags: r, lubridate

bom dia.
É minha primeira postagem aqui. Acabo de iniciar minha jornada no “R” e estou com uma dificuldade com datas. Eu até que consegui chegar ao resultado que eu queria, no entanto, dei uma volta, no meu entender, MUITO grande. Acredito que haja uma forma mais simples de fazer o que eu fiz.
A questão é: alguém conhece uma forma mais simples de nomear os meses no caso de um dataset desorganizado importado de um arquivo “.csv”?
Não sei se fui claro na minha pergunta, por isso vou colocar meu percurso:

Importei os dados e gravei no objeto "fen" usando:

```
fen<-read.csv("Noronha.csv", sep=";")
```

No entanto, como não sei carregar o arquivo aqui, vou colocar os vetores para que seja possível reproduzir o data frame tal como obtive:

```
Ano<-c(2012:2020)
Janeiro<-c(112,127,121,131,150,158,137,165,164)
Fevereiro<-c(101,101,94,114,126,119,122,138,144)
Marco<-c(97,101,101,123,126,138,137,154,114)
Abril<-c(97,94,97,122,125,141,129,142,6)
Maio<-c(96,98,98,136,126,135,136,144,4)
```

Gravo o dataframe com o nome de “fen”:

```
fen<-data.frame(Ano, Janeiro, Fevereiro, Marco, Abril, Maio)
```

O resultado (o mesmo da importação do .csv) vai ser este:

```
   Ano Janeiro Fevereiro Marco Abril Maio
1 2012     112       101    97    97   96
2 2013     127       101   101    94   98
3 2014     121        94   101    97   98
4 2015     131       114   123   122  136
5 2016     150       126   126   125  126
6 2017     158       119   138   141  135
7 2018     137       122   137   129  136
8 2019     165       138   154   142  144
9 2020     164       144   114     6    4
```

Daí começa minha saga:
Carrego os pacotes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Em seguida, uso a função “gather” para organizar o dataframe e gravo no mesmo objeto “fen”:

```
fen<-gather(fen, Mes, Voos, c("Janeiro":"Maio"))
```

Resultado:

```
    Ano       Mes Voos
1  2012   Janeiro  112
2  2013   Janeiro  127
3  2014   Janeiro  121
4  2015   Janeiro  131
5  2016   Janeiro  150
6  2017   Janeiro  158
7  2018   Janeiro  137
8  2019   Janeiro  165
9  2020   Janeiro  164
10 2012 Fevereiro  101
11 2013 Fevereiro  101
12 2014 Fevereiro   94
13 2015 Fevereiro  114
14 2016 Fevereiro  126
15 2017 Fevereiro  119
16 2018 Fevereiro  122
17 2019 Fevereiro  138
18 2020 Fevereiro  144
19 2012     Março   97
20 2013     Março  101
21 2014     Março  101
22 2015     Março  123
23 2016     Março  126
24 2017     Março  138
25 2018     Março  137
26 2019     Março  154
27 2020     Março  114
28 2012     Abril   97
29 2013     Abril   94
30 2014     Abril   97
31 2015     Abril  122
32 2016     Abril  125
33 2017     Abril  141
34 2018     Abril  129
35 2019     Abril  142
36 2020     Abril    6
37 2012      Maio   96
38 2013      Maio   98
39 2014      Maio   98
40 2015      Maio  136
41 2016      Maio  126
42 2017      Maio  135
43 2018      Maio  136
44 2019      Maio  144
45 2020      Maio    4
```

Depois, para pode converter no formato data, preciso criar os dias.
Daí crio um vetor com o dia “1” para cada uma das linhas:

```
dia<-c(rep("1", 45))
```

E, depois, uso o “cbind” para juntar ao data frame principal. Gravo com o mesmo nome “fen”:

```
fen<-cbind(fen, dia)
```

Depois, uso a função “unite” para juntar ano, mês e dia, em uma coluna chamada “dt”:

```
fen<-fen%>%
  unite(Ano, Mes, dia, col=dt, sep = "-")
```

Checo a qual classe pertence esse coluna “dt”.
Constato que é do tipo “chr”

```
str(fen)
'data.frame':   45 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dt  : chr  "2012-Janeiro-1" "2013-Janeiro-1" "2014-Janeiro-1" "2015-Janeiro-1" ...
 $ Voos: int  112 127 121 131 150 158 137 165 164 101 ...
```

Em seguida, uso a função “as.POSIXct” para gravar a recém-criada coluna “dt” no formato “date”

```
fen$dt<-as.POSIXct(fen$dt, format="%Y-%B-%d")
```

E confiro a classe:

```
    'data.frame':   45 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dt  : POSIXct, format: "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
 $ Voos: int  112 127 121 131 150 158 137 165 164 101 ...
```

Rodei o Cheat sheet do lubridate e não consegui transformar esse o formato “2012-01-01” em “2012-Jan-01”. Então, criei uma nova coluna chamada “mes_abbr”, usando a função “month” do lubridate.

```
mes_abbr<-month(fen$dt, label = T, abbr = T)
```

Depois, adicionei-a ao dataframe usando o “cbind”. Criei um novo dataframe (“fen2”)

```
fen2<-cbind(fen, mes_abbr)
```

Finalmente, criei um outro dataframe (“fen3”): 1) separando a coluna “dt”, 2) escolhendo as colunas que me interessavam (ano, mês abreviado e voos) e 3) ordenando por ano e mês:

```
fen3<-fen2%>%
  separate(dt, into=c("ano", "mes", "dia"))%>%
  select(ano, mes_abbr, Voos)%>%
  arrange(ano, mes)
```

O resultado:

```
    ano mes_abbr Voos
1  2012      jan  112
2  2012      fev  101
3  2012      mar   97
4  2012      abr   97
5  2012      mai   96
6  2013      jan  127
7  2013      fev  101
8  2013      mar  101
9  2013      abr   94
10 2013      mai   98
11 2014      jan  121
12 2014      fev   94
13 2014      mar  101
14 2014      abr   97
15 2014      mai   98
16 2015      jan  131
17 2015      fev  114
18 2015      mar  123
19 2015      abr  122
20 2015      mai  136
21 2016      jan  150
22 2016      fev  126
23 2016      mar  126
24 2016      abr  125
25 2016      mai  126
26 2017      jan  158
27 2017      fev  119
28 2017      mar  138
29 2017      abr  141
30 2017      mai  135
31 2018      jan  137
32 2018      fev  122
33 2018      mar  137
34 2018      abr  129
35 2018      mai  136
36 2019      jan  165
37 2019      fev  138
38 2019      mar  154
39 2019      abr  142
40 2019      mai  144
41 2020      jan  164
42 2020      fev  144
43 2020      mar  114
44 2020      abr    6
45 2020      mai    4
```

Pronto, assim consegui colocar no formato que eu queria e alcancei meu objetivo: fazer um gráfico que viesse no eixo “X” o mês abreviado.

No entanto, algo me diz que há um jeito bem mais simples de chegar a esse resultado. Se alguém puder me ajudar com isso, agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

Se só precisa do mês abreviado, basta ficar com as 3 primeiras letras dessa coluna. Isso faz-se com a função R base `substr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fen <- fen %>% 
  gather(Mes, Voos, c("Janeiro":"Maio")) %>%
  mutate(mes_abbr = substr(Mes, 1, 3)) %>%
  select(Ano, mes_abbr, Voos)

head(fen)
#   Ano mes_abbr Voos
#1 2012      Jan  112
#2 2013      Jan  127
#3 2014      Jan  121
#4 2015      Jan  131
#5 2016      Jan  150
#6 2017      Jan  158
```

## Gráfico

Para fazer um gráfico `ggplot` a partir dos dados originais, não é necessário criar duas bases adicionais, pode-se fazer tudo com *pipe*.
Vou ainda usar o pacote `zoo`, função [`as.yearmon`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-8/topics/yearmon).

```
library(ggplot2)

fen %>% 
  gather(Mes, Voos, c("Janeiro":"Maio")) %>%
  mutate(Mes = tolower(Mes),
         Data = paste(Ano, Mes, 1, sep = "-"),
         Data = as.Date(Data, "%Y-%B-%d"),
         Data = zoo::as.yearmon(Data)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Data, Voos)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Rui. Foi bom poq conheci uma função nova. Mas não atende minha necessidade, pois quando faço isso a coluna é lida como texto, o que significa que quando tento agrupar por Ano, Mes (usando arrange), o mes de Abril, vem antes de Fevereiro, que, por seu turno, vem antes de Janeiro. Daí quebra a lógica dos meses do ano, pois meu propósito final é plotar um gráfico.

Comment: @itamar Veja agora. Com a função `as.yearmon` tem-se as datas por ordem cronológica.

Comment: @itamar Note ainda que o pipe pode acabar logo após `Data = as.Date(etc)` e ir diretamente para `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelas dicas Rui Barradas. Continuei pesquisando e testando e encontrei essa outra possibilidade:

Criei um novo objeto "fen3".

Usei a funcao "paste0" para colar na coluna "dt" o "Ano", o "Mes" e acrescento uma coluna só com "01" (para os dias). Concatenei (%>%) com...

...a função "ymd()" do lubridate para converter no formato "yyyy-mm-dd" e, ao mesmo tempo...

criei a coluna "ano" e atribui o os atributos da parte "year" da coluna "dt" recem-criada

fiz o mesmo para a coluna "mes", mas ai, o pulo do gato foi a conversao do mes na forma abreviada usando os recursos da funcao "month" do lubridate

criei a coluna "dia"

selecionei a coluna "ano", "mes", "n_voos"

organizei por "ano" e "mes".

E ai ficou organizado porque agora ele esta reconhendo essa coluna como "date" e nao como "character"

```
fen3<-fen2%>%
  mutate(dt=paste0(Ano, Mes, "01")%>%
           ymd(),
         ano=year(dt),
         mes=month(dt, abbr=T, label = T),
         dia=day(dt))%>%
  select(ano, mes, n_voos)%>%
  arrange(ano, mes)
```

Resultado:

```
ano mes n_voos
1  2012 jan    112
2  2012 fev    101
3  2012 mar     97
4  2012 abr     97
5  2012 mai     96
6  2013 jan    127
7  2013 fev    101
8  2013 mar    101
9  2013 abr     94
10 2013 mai     98
11 2014 jan    121
12 2014 fev     94
13 2014 mar    101
14 2014 abr     97
15 2014 mai     98
16 2015 jan    131
17 2015 fev    114
18 2015 mar    123
19 2015 abr    122
20 2015 mai    136
21 2016 jan    150
22 2016 fev    126
23 2016 mar    126
24 2016 abr    125
25 2016 mai    126
26 2017 jan    158
27 2017 fev    119
28 2017 mar    138
29 2017 abr    141
30 2017 mai    135
31 2018 jan    137
32 2018 fev    122
33 2018 mar    137
34 2018 abr    129
35 2018 mai    136
36 2019 jan    165
37 2019 fev    138
38 2019 mar    154
39 2019 abr    142
40 2019 mai    144
41 2020 jan    164
42 2020 fev    144
43 2020 mar    114
44 2020 abr      6
45 2020 mai      4
```

Depois, plotei o grafico:
agrupando as variaveis por ano...

...atribuindo mes no eixo "X", "n_voos" no eixo "Y" e alterei as cores usando a funcao "color" e atribuindo o "as.factor()" por ano.

```
ggplot(aes(group=ano))+
  geom_line(aes(mes, n_voos, color= as.factor(ano)))
```

So nao consegui alterar o titulo da legenda no grafico. Ficou como "color= as.factor(ano)".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]